# iOS to PHP wrong encoding (non english becomes gibberish)

Tags: php, iphone, ios, http, ios4

I ran into a problem communicating between an iphone app and my php server.

The problem shows when I send non english characters via a post request. The english data is OK but the non english looks like this: `×ž×›×œ×œ×ª ××•×¨×•×ª ×™×©×¨××œ` when the server recieves it.

What could be the problem? I am using the ASI library for the request.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you're using unicode encoding on both the iPhone and the server. I believe that NSString is unicode by default so I would guess that you're converting to ansi on the server and that's what is causing the problem.

Comment: no, it's not the problem. the page encodings really wasn't unicode, but after changing it to UTF8 nothing changed... both the server and the iphone code are unicode.